# Strange unknown identifier error

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors

Im working on a project working wth visual studio 2013 and programming in c++. For some reason i do not understand i got an unknown identifier error while compiling my project. I have seached for 2 days now for an answer havent found anything that could get me in the right direction.

Error mesage: `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Mesh'`.

**Mesh header**

```
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include "Renderer.h"

class Mesh
{
public:
    GLuint GetVao();
    GLuint GetVbo();
    GLuint GetSize();

    void AddVertex(const glm::vec3& position);
    void SendData();
    void Destroy();

private:
    std::vector<GLfloat> verticies;
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo;
    GLuint size;
};

#endif
```

**Mesh source**

```
#include "Mesh.h"

void Mesh::AddVertex(const glm::vec3& position)
{
    verticies.push_back(position.x);
    verticies.push_back(position.y);
    verticies.push_back(position.z);
}

void Mesh::Destroy()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    verticies.clear();
}

void Mesh::SendData()
{
    if (vao == 0)
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    if (vbo == 0)
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, vbo);

    glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, verticies.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), verticies.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(Renderer::GetInstance()->GetSceneShader()->GetPositionLocation());

    glVertexAttribPointer(Renderer::GetInstance()->GetSceneShader()->GetPositionLocation(), 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
} 

GLuint Mesh::GetVao()
{
    return vao;
}

GLuint Mesh::GetVbo()
{
    return vbo;
}

GLuint Mesh::GetSize()
{
    return size;
}
```

The error comes from the Renderer header file.

**Renderer head**

```
#ifndef RENDERER_H
#define RENDERER_H

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "SceneShader.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

class Renderer
{
public:
    static Renderer* GetInstance()
    {
        static Renderer instance;
        return &instance;
    }

    void Initialize();
    void PreDraw();
    void Destroy();
    void DrawMesh(Mesh* mesh);

    SceneShader* GetSceneShader();

protected:
    virtual ~Renderer();

private:
    Renderer();
    SceneShader sceneShader;
};

#endif;
```

Renderer source:

```
#include "Renderer.h"

Renderer::Renderer()
{
}

Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    Destroy();
}

void Renderer::Initialize()
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    sceneShader.Create();
    sceneShader.Bind();
}

void Renderer::PreDraw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void Renderer::Destroy()
{
    sceneShader.Unbind();
    sceneShader.Destroy();
}

SceneShader* Renderer::GetSceneShader()
{
    return &sceneShader;
}

void Renderer::DrawMesh(Mesh* mesh)
{
    glBindVertexArray(mesh->GetVao());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh->GetSize());
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: Cyclic include dependency: `Mesh.h` includes `Renderer.h` and vice-versa. Plenty of SO posts on that kind of thing.

Comment: Not really related to the question but you probably have a defect on your Renderer class. It seems to be implemented as a singleton but you don't suppress the default copy constructor and copy assignment ( and move constructor and assignment in C++11 ) the compiler will provide for this class. This way code like `Renderer r = *Renderer::GetInstance();` will compile and create a copy of the singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a cyclic include. When `Mesh.h` is being preprocessed, it includes `Renderer.h`, which then needs to include `Mesh.h`. Since you have inclusion guards, `Mesh.h` cannot be included again, so `Renderer` won't be able to see the declaration/definition of `Mesh`.

This is easily fixable by using `#include` more appropriately:

1. `Mesh.h` doesn't even need to include `Renderer.h` (it doesn't use it at all).
2. `Mesh.cpp` *does* need `Renderer.h` though, so it should be included at the top of that file.
3. `Renderer.h` also doesn't need to include `Mesh.h`. Since all it has is a pointer to `Mesh`, you can make do with just a forward declaration. So replace `#include "Mesh.h"` with `class Mesh;`.

Answer (score 1):

`Mesh.h` includes `Renderer.h` which tries to include `Mesh.h`. The result is that one class definition appears before the other, so the second hasn't been declared when it's referred to by the first.

In cases like this, at least one class can manage with only a declaration of the other. That's the case here; `Renderer` only needs a declaration of `Mesh`:

```
class Mesh;
```

since it only uses the name to declare pointers and function parameters. `Mesh` doesn't need to know about `Renderer` at all, since it exploits the invisible coupling of the singleton anti-pattern, so simply remove that include.

Each source file will need to include both headers, since they use both classes in ways that require a definition. `Renderer.h` will still need to include `SceneShader.h`, since it declares an object of that type.